# How can I restore rhythmbox icon in bottom panel?

Tags: gnome, rhythmbox

I installed gnome-shell from the Ubuntu Gnome-Shell Remix ppa with Ubuntu 12.04.
I tried rhythmbox and liked it. Since i want to use my top right panel as a system manager (halt, sound, battery and network only) and my bottom right panel as my hidden app manager (like the systray used to do) I was happy to find a rhythmbox icon with a gnome-shell menu to manage my music and the software in my bottom panel.

Unluckily, i clicked on some sort of "Hide" in this menu and I never saw my rhythmbox icon again. I would like to restore it, because rhythmbox does not exit when pressing the X button and then I can't manage it, i have to relaunch it. How can I restore this button ? I tried to remove the config files and reinstall but I don't have this pretty useful icon.

Also, is there a way to change default applications in gnome-shell ? I can't find an option dialog for it like I had in Xfce and ol'Gnome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/55/media-player-indicator/ and just click the switch to on and it will install the extension to gnome shell that you need to be able to control Rhythmbox or any other audio program that has D-Bus control activated. See the discussion on the page to activate the necessary setting or plugin to make it work for all sorts of different audio programs.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.10 with Gnome 3.38 you need a updated version of media-player-indicator that is [Mpris Indicator Button](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1379/mpris-indicator-button/) by JasonLG1979.